# Angular testing of a failing promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-promise, httpbackend

I am trying to test a failing promise

```
service 'resolveService' function:

     return {resolveRedirect: function(){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                  $http.jsonp('randomUrl')
                    .then(function(response){
                      jsonpResponse.responseHandler(response.data);
                      deferred.resolve(1);
                    }, function(err){
                      jsonpResponse.responseHandler({});
                      deferred.resolve(err);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
              },
           }
```

I want the test a failing promise and wrote the following:

```
    spyOn(jsonpResponse,'responseHandler');

    $httpBackend.expectJSONP('randomUrl').respond(400, {});

    var promise = resolveService.resolveRedirect();

    var result;

    promise.then(function(data){
      console.log('we are in success');
      expect(true).toEqual(false);
    },function(err){
      console.log('we are in error');
      result = err;
      expect(result).toEqual(err);
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(jsonpResponse.responseHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith({});
```

When running this test, it fails by saying that `expect(true).toEqual(false);` is wrong. Also the console tells me, that the promise acutally succeeds and prompts 'we are in success'. EDIT: It goes to the wrong block. It is supposed to go into "we are in error".

Where am I wrong? As I am expecting a `400 error`, the promise should fail and the test should pass right?

Comment: Of course it will throw an error on that line - How can true ever equal false?

Comment: The promise should never reach this part as I expect it to fail. Therefore it should go straight to the part with "we are in error". But it never goes there, it goes to the "success" block.

Comment: @Dribel change `deferred.resolve(err)` to `deferred.reject(err)` in reject section

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski great that works. THANKS. However, I have to resolve this promise and I can't ever reject it (it's part of a resolve block it $state which needs to be resolved). Is there another way to make this work?

Comment: Sorry, I just got it. @KrzysztofSafjanowski thanks again.